# What Path Should I Return for the Non-Null Pattern?

Tags: java, file-io, io, path, nio

If I have a method that applies the non null return pattern what should I return when I have to return a `Path` (The one from `NIO`)? I was thinking `Paths.get("");`, but is this appropriate?

Comment: This depends entirely on what the method does.

Comment: Also depends on what the method is document to do.  I'll add the the "Non-null return pattern" is not universal and not always a good idea.  Caveat emptor.